# Post not passing array in postgres query

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

My goal is to post multiple selected options from an html form as a variable in a php query. I believe that having the select tag id set as an array using brackets should allow multiple selections to pass, but my concern is that they are not formatted in a manner that the query will recognize the data as an array. The current results show just the response for the last selected option from the post.

Here is the select tag from the form (note that it is populated by a separate query, maybe someone can state how to add the formatting to the menu variable here... Should be formatted like this... 'COMM_0001%','COMM_0002%', and so on:

```
<select multiple name="userMedia" class="form-control" id="userMedia[]" 
style="height:350px;">
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("database login data deleted");
if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT medias.name FROM public.medias where medias.startdate > '2015-01-01'";
$rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);


if (pg_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
$menu .= "<option value=".$row['name'].">" . $row['name']. "</option>";
}
}

echo $menu;

pg_close($conn); 

?> 
</select>
```

Here is the query that this data gets posted to...

```
$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$media= $_POST['userMedia'];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];

if( !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && 
(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post')===0)  ) {
// Create connection
$conn = pg_connect("Connect Info Deleted");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}

$result = pg_query($conn,
"SELECT
date (b.starttime),
Count(b.starttime) as Plays,
Count(distinct(b.playerid)) as Stores

FROM
public.billing b,
public.medias m,
public.players p

WHERE
b.mediaitemid = m.id and
p.id = b.playerid and
m.name LIKE any (array['$media%']) and
b.starttime >= date('$datea') and 
b.starttime < date('$datez')+1 and
m.startdate >  '2015-01-01'

GROUP BY
date (b.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (b.starttime);");

if (!$result) {
echo "Query failed.\n";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$media` is an array. You can't substitute an array directly into a string (it just puts the word `Array` there). You should use `implode()` to convert it to a comma-separated list. You also need to put quotes around each name, and escape it to prevent SQL injection.

```
$media_names = implode(',', array_map(function($n) use ($conn) {
    return "'" . pg_escape_string($conn, $n) . "'";
}, $media);
```

Then you can substitute `media_names` into the query instead of `$media`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be moving in the right direction... Though, could you explain where in the code this would go?

Comment: Anywhere between `$media = $_POST['userMedia'];` and `$result = pg_query(...)`